# Python script to rename a folder if the folder name similar to line in a text file to that exact line

Tags: python, directory, file-rename

I am working on a script in which I have a text file that contains name like

```
abc_3
bcd_5
def_3
```

And I have a folders like:

abc
   bcd
   def

The script should rename the folder to the filename with underscore if the name is similar.So that my folders will also become like

```
abc_3
bcd_5
def_3.
```

So far I Have written this:

```
import os, sys, subprocess
import csv
import re
import glob
Folder_dir = os.listdir('/path/to/folders')

for folders in Folder_dir:
        print folders
        Txt_file = open("/vedata/detectionname.txt", "r") # The text file location
        for line in Txt_file:
            if folders in line: #How to match folders name??
                print line
```

Comment: you should have a look at the library `os`. You should be able to do what you want

Comment: os.rename yes. But first I Need to match it

Comment: you can match the folder name with the line name with regex: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#

Comment: Will regex be useful as ihave the folder names with me not looking for some pattern

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean similar. Similar prefixes ? Prefix can be easily handled by `String.startswith()` !!

Comment: Well it will work with regex but maybe its a bit over the top for the problem. You just want to check whether the folder name is the substring of a given string, if this is the case you want to change to folder name to this string, right? line.find(folders)  should do the job

Comment: If the folder names are sufficiently distinct, but not all just prefixes, it can be good to sorted(list(name)), which will give you all the letters in the name, and compare how many match between the two

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for you:

```
import os

folders_path = '/path/to/folders'
folders = os.listdir(folders_path)

for folder in folders:
    with open("folders.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.read().splitlines():
            if folder in line:
                os.rename(
                    os.path.join(folders_path, folder),
                    os.path.join(folders_path, line)
                )
```

**Note:**

[`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement allows you to make sure that the file would be closed even is an exception is raised.

Comment: the txt file is a separate file wich could be or could be not in a same location.I tried this code but folder are not renamed

Comment: Just replace `folders.txt` with the path to your text file.

Comment: try to put the text file at the same level as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing folders name is as simple as **os.rename(old, new)**:

```
path = '/path/to/folders'
folder_dir = os.listdir(folders_path)

for folder_name in folder_dir:
        with open("/vedata/detectionname.txt", "r") as txt_file:
            for line in txt_file.readlines():
                line_stripped = line.split('-')[0]
                if folder_name.startswith(line_stripped): 
                    os.rename(path + folder_name, path + line)
                    break
```

I've also changed the code to `with` to open as it closes it automatically once done.

I referred the `path` so the rename explicitly works on full path.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154456/discussion-on-answer-by-vinny-python-script-to-rename-a-folder-if-the-folder-nam).